# Film where a family moves to a town where a witch's curse kills all the children

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

In this movie, I think it was on chiller or fearnet, a dad, his wife the stepmom, her daughter and his daughter and their new baby Nathan move to a town that has no children. Some time before the town killed a woman’s baby and she, a witch, cursed the town so a demon or monster or something kills all children. The dad’s daughter has a friend or boyfriend named Kyle and I know he gets killed by the monster. And when it’s nearby there’s a really bad smell in the air.
And for the life of me I can’t find the movie

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this?

Answer (score 7):

Is this the Syfy channel film, ***[Goblin](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1512310/)*** (2010)...?

> Every Halloween, a small hamlet in the deep woods is visited by a fierce goblin, intent on capturing infants and brutally murdering anyone in its path.

On Halloween in 1831, the residents of a small town conduct an annual ritual which involves them throwing things they consider to be unclean into a bonfire to cleanse the town of evil. This year, one of the things they decide to throw into the bonfire is a woman's "misshapen, diseased" baby; they seize it from her arms and toss it in right in front of her. Enraged, she reveals herself as a witch and curses the town so that no child will be safe there during the hours of Halloween. Moments later, a [goblin](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Goblin_(Goblin)) emerges from the bonfire and pursues another woman holding a baby, killing her.

The film then jumps forward to October 30th in the "present day," and we're introduced to Neil Perkins and his family, who're driving to the same town with the hopes of developing it and making money. Travelling with Neil are his second wife, Kate, his 17-year-old daughter, Nikki, her infant half-brother, Nathan, and her friend, Cammy. Around 25 minutes into the film, Nikki and Cammy run into Kyle, a friend and love interest of Nikki's who happens to be staying at his uncle's house nearby.

The following morning, the goblin emerges from the site of the bonfire again and starts hunting any babies in the area, killing anyone who gets in its way. The goblin is repeatedly detected before it's seen by its awful stench, and Kyle is one of the people that it kills.

It isn't specifically stated that there are no babies or children in the town, but we don't see any there in the present day, aside from Nathan and the baby of a couple driving on a country road. We're also shown newspaper clippings documenting the unexplained disappearance of babies in the town in recent decades.

I found this 'trailer' on YouTube, although it appears to be the opening scene of the film, rather than a trailer in the usual sense.